# Incremental learning PLPython(3)u

Tags: postgresql, plpython

Is there a way to use incremental machine learning with plpython3u in postgres database?

Comment: Whatever you can do in Python you can do in PL/Python.

Answer (score 1):

plpython3u can execute any python3 code, so if you can do it in python, then in theory yes you can do it in plpython.

Checking wikipedia...

> Incremental learning, or online learning, is a branch of machine learning that involves processing incoming data from a data stream—continuously and in real time

This sounds like a long-running process.

In general it is a good idea to avoid having very long transactions if you can, because they can hold locks and prevent efficient vacuum. So the better context to do it would be a plpythonu stored procedure (not a function), as this can commit the current [transaction](https://postgresdocs.github.io/plpython-transactions.html) and start a new one. Also if you want the output of your long running python script to be visible to other transactions, it will have to commit, and only a stored procedure can do that.

It will not necessarily be faster than using an independent python process, because it will run on the same machine as postgres, which means all resources will be shared between postgres and the python program. I'm mentioning this because machine learning tends to be a huge consumer of both CPU and RAM...